Infinite Summation of Almost Sure Convergent RVs
Suppose we have random variables $X_{n,i}$ for $n\geq1,i=1,\dots,b_n$. Here we suppose $b_n$ is non-decreasing. We know that for each $i$, the sequence $X_{n,i}$ converges to $X_i$ almost sure.
Now we would like to look at the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{b_n} X_{n,i}$ and whether it converges to $\sum_{i=1}^{b_{\infty}} X_{i}$, where $b_n\to b_{\infty}$.
If $b_{\infty}<\infty$, we can find a joint $N_0$: for all $i$, when $n>N_0$ we have $\vert X_{n,i} - X_i\vert < \epsilon/{b_{\infty}}$ on some zero-measured set. Then we can show $\sum_{i=1}^{b_n} X_{n,i}$ converges to $\sum_{i=1}^{b_{\infty}} X_{i}$ almost sure.
But what if $b_{\infty}=\infty$, do we still have $\sum_{i=1}^{b_n} X_{n,i}\to\sum_{i=1}^{b_{\infty}} X_{i}$, or do we need some extra conditions?

Note that by setting $X_{n,i} = 0$ for $i>b_n$ the statement is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_{n,i} \to \sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ almost-surely as $n\to \infty$. In turn, by considering the (countable) intersection of the events $\{X_{n,i} \to X_i\text{ as } n\to \infty\}$ over $i\ge 1$, this is itself equivalent to showing that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{n,i} \to \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ as $n\to \infty$ for any collection of reals $\{x_{n,i}\}_{n,i\ge 0}$ such that $x_{n,i} \to x_i$ as $n\to \infty$ for each $i\ge 1$.
However this is certainly false - for example taking $$x_{n,i} = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n} & \text{if }1\le i\le n \\ 0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and $x_i= 0$ for all $i$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{n,i} = 1 \not \to \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i = 0$.
